# Ruby Koans: explicit scoping on a class definition part 2

Tags: ruby

I wanted to clarify some things off of this original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627735/ruby-explicit-scoping-on-a-class-definition/4629832#4629832). The answer suggested that Ruby searches for the constant definition in this order:

1. The enclosing scope
2. Any outer scopes (repeat until top level is reached)
3. Included modules
4. Superclass(es)
5. Object
6. Kernel

So to clarify, at which step (1-6) is the value for the constant `LEGS` found for `legs_in_oyster`? Is it from the Superclass `Animal`? Is the scope of class `MyAnimals` ignored because it is not considered an enclosing scope? Is this due to the explicit `MyAnimals::Oyster` class definition?

Thanks! Just trying to understand. Here is the code:

```
 class Animal
   LEGS = 4
   def legs_in_animal
     LEGS
   end

   class NestedAnimal
     def legs_in_nested_animal
       LEGS
     end
   end
 end

 def test_nested_classes_inherit_constants_from_enclosing_classes
   assert_equal 4, Animal::NestedAnimal.new.legs_in_nested_animal
 end

 # ------------------------------------------------------------------

 class MyAnimals
   LEGS = 2

   class Bird < Animal
     def legs_in_bird
       LEGS
     end
   end
 end

 def test_who_wins_with_both_nested_and_inherited_constants
   assert_equal 2, MyAnimals::Bird.new.legs_in_bird
 end

 # QUESTION: Which has precedence: The constant in the lexical scope,
 # or the constant from the inheritance heirarachy?

 # ------------------------------------------------------------------

 class MyAnimals::Oyster < Animal
   def legs_in_oyster
     LEGS
   end
 end

 def test_who_wins_with_explicit_scoping_on_class_definition
   assert_equal 4, MyAnimals::Oyster.new.legs_in_oyster
 end

 # QUESTION: Now Which has precedence: The constant in the lexical
 # scope, or the constant from the inheritance heirarachy?  Why is it
 # different than the previous answer?
 end
```

Comment: Someone's asked about this koan before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627735/ruby-explicit-scoping-on-a-class-definition

Comment: @Andrew - I specified that in the post. I'm just trying to build more discussion on the topic because there are parts that I didn't understand. Should I just comment there?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was just pondering the very same question from the very same koan. I am no expert at scoping, but the following simple explanation made a lot of sense to me, and maybe it will help you as well.

When you define `MyAnimals::Oyster` you are still in the global scope, so ruby has no knowledge of the `LEGS` value set to 2 in `MyAnimals` because you never actually are in the scope of `MyAnimals` (a little counterintuitive).

However, things would be different if you were to define `Oyster` this way:

```
class MyAnimals
  class Oyster < Animal
    def legs_in_oyster
      LEGS # => 2
    end
  end
end
```

The difference is that in the code above, by the time you define `Oyster`, you have dropped into the scope of `MyAnimals`, so ruby knows that `LEGS` refers to `MyAnimals::LEGS` (2) and not `Animal::LEGS` (4).

FYI, I got this insight from the following URL (referenced in the question you linked to):

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.ruby/t5rtDNol3P8

Comment: Thanks @bowsersenior! I saw that link but didn't read down far enough. User error.

Comment: I think it should be `Oyster < Animal`