# Ruby Koans: scoping part 3

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, scope

After reading several posts regarding this ruby koans scoping problem, [read first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464811/ruby-koans-explicit-scoping-on-a-class-definition-part-2), I found myself asking a question:

What is the advantage of being able to define a subclass say `class Oyster` in the form of say `class MyAnimals::Oyster < Animal` rather than nested in the `Animal` class? As this is a contrived example, I don't expect this to be explained using this example, but as I try to understand scope, I imagine there is a usefulness to having the nested lexical scope as having priority over inherited hierarchy. I think another question that gets at my confusion (which may be answered in a later koan) is does `class MyAnimals::Oyster < Animal` insides lie in the `Animal` class in a subclass of `MyAnimals::Oyster` or `Oyster` and if so, what does `MyAnimals::` do exactly?

Comment: `MyAnimals::Oyster`, `MyAnimals` is a module.

Comment: I figured that a more subtle understanding of modules, classes and objects was how I would come to understand this question. Thanks. In the ruby koans, I haven't yet reached the about_modules section, so fun ahead.