# Ruby scopes, constants precedence: lexical scope or inheritance tree

Tags: ruby, nested-class, scopes

I'll show your the code snippet from [rubykoans](http://rubykoans.com/) tutorial. Consider the next code:

```
class MyAnimals
LEGS = 2

  class Bird < Animal
    def legs_in_bird
      LEGS
    end
  end
end

def test_who_wins_with_both_nested_and_inherited_constants
  assert_equal 2, MyAnimals::Bird.new.legs_in_bird
end

# QUESTION: Which has precedence: The constant in the lexical scope,
# or the constant from the inheritance hierarchy?
# ------------------------------------------------------------------

class MyAnimals::Oyster < Animal
  def legs_in_oyster
    LEGS
  end
end

def test_who_wins_with_explicit_scoping_on_class_definition
  assert_equal 4, MyAnimals::Oyster.new.legs_in_oyster
end

# QUESTION: Now which has precedence: The constant in the lexical
# scope, or the constant from the inheritance hierarchy?  Why is it
# **different than the previous answer**?
```

Actually the question is in comments (I highlighted it with asteriks (though it intended to be in bold)). Can anybody explain me please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 35):

This is answered here: [Ruby: explicit scoping on a class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627735/ruby-explicit-scoping-on-a-class-definition). But perhaps it's not super clear. If you read the linked article it will help you with the answer.

Basically, `Bird` is declared in the scope of `MyAnimals`, which has a higher precedence when resolving constants. `Oyster` is in the `MyAnimals` namespace, but it is not declared in that scope.

Inserting `p Module.nesting` into each class with show you what the enclosing scopes are.

```
class MyAnimals
  LEGS = 2

  class Bird < Animal

    p Module.nesting
    def legs_in_bird
      LEGS
    end
  end
end
```

Yields: `[AboutConstants::MyAnimals::Bird, AboutConstants::MyAnimals, AboutConstants]`

And

```
class MyAnimals::Oyster < Animal
  p Module.nesting

  def legs_in_oyster
    LEGS
  end
end
```

Yields: `[AboutConstants::MyAnimals::Oyster, AboutConstants]`

See the difference?

Comment: Including `Module.nesting` made this answer an excellent addition to those you linked.